# R ggplot . HOW TO plot only the variables >0?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting the number of covid19 PCR in the towns of my province. The problem its that many town haven´t any PCR positive. I need a way to plot only the towns with at least 1+ PCR.

This is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library('data.table') 

dfcsv1 <- read.csv("https://dadesobertes.gva.es/datastore/dump/ee17a346-a596-4866-a2ac-a530eb811737?bom=True", 
                   encoding = "UTF-8", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
colnames(dfcsv1) <- c("code","code2","Municipio", "PCR", "TasaPCR", "PCR14", 
                      "TasaPCR14", "Muertos", "TasaMuertos")

dfcsv1$TasaMuertos = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",dfcsv1$TasaMuertos))
dfcsv1$TasaPCR = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",dfcsv1$TasaPCR))
dfcsv1$TasaPCR14 = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",dfcsv1$TasaPCR14))

dfcsv1 %>%
  mutate(Municipio = fct_reorder(Municipio, PCR14)) %>%  
  
  ggplot(aes(x=Municipio, y=PCR14, fill =TasaPCR14)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.6) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(data=dfcsv1, aes(y=PCR14,label=PCR14),vjust=1)+  
  scale_fill_gradient(low="steelblue", high="red")
```

Comment: Maybe try `dfcsv1 %>% filter(PCR14>0) %>%` before `mutate()`

Comment: Add a `filter` right after `mutate` and before `ggplot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, you need to filter out the `PCR14` that is greater than 0 before reordering the factor levels. However, you will also need to remove the `data` parameter from `geom_text`, otherwise all those factor levels come back and you will have a big mess. It's already a bit crowded with the zero levels removed.

I think you should also change the `vjust` to an `hjust` to put the text in a nicer position since you have flipped the coordinates, with a compensating increase in the (flipped) y axis range to accommodate it:

```
dfcsv1 %>%
  filter(PCR14 > 0) %>%
  mutate(Municipio = fct_reorder(Municipio, PCR14)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Municipio, y = PCR14, fill = TasaPCR14)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.6) + 
    coord_flip() +
    geom_text(aes(y = PCR14,label = PCR14), hjust= -0.5) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "steelblue", high = "red") +
    ylim(c(0, 45))
```

[image]

Incidentally, it looks a lot better with the ones removed too:

```
    dfcsv1 %>%
      filter(PCR14 > 1) %>%
      mutate(Municipio = fct_reorder(Municipio, PCR14)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=Municipio, y=PCR14, fill =TasaPCR14)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.6) + coord_flip() +
      geom_text(aes(y=PCR14,label=PCR14),hjust=-0.5)+  
      scale_fill_gradient(low="steelblue", high="red") +
      ylim(c(0, 45))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, regardless of the type of plot or whether you are using `ggplot` , `lattice` or the base `plot` function,  subsetting should happen first.

```
plot(x[y>0] , y[y>0])
```

The rest is aesthetics.